# Как разместить виджет/кнопку/текст PySimpleGUI в заданных координатах

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui

Я не знаю как это сделать без `Tkinter`. Нашел только как это сделать в `Tkinter`

```
b = tk.Button(self.YoureName,text='Button')
b.place(x=120,y=62)
```

Если можете дайте хорошую документацию на `PySimpleGUI`/`Tkinter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если можете дайте хорошую документацию на

PySimpleGUI - https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Там есть пример, как разместить окно window2 относительно окна window1:

```
window2.move(window1.current_location()[0], window1.current_location()[1] + 220)
```

TkInter. "Программирование GUI на Python". Светлана Шапошникова
https://younglinux.info/tkinter/course

Рекомендую скачать в виде PDF - там с исходами.